# Is the Excel "Last Modified" time adjusted to my timezone?

Tags: microsoft-excel, timestamp, time-zone

I'm looking at a Last Modified time stamp in an Excel Workbook:

[image: Excel Workbook Last Modified info]

I got the spreadsheet from China, and I'm sitting in Denmark. These two countries are in two different time zones, and I would thus like to know if the time (11:02) is the local time in China when the spreadsheet was updated, or if it's converted to my local time on my computer.

Note: I'm not trying to do this programmatically - I just want to know if I have to deduct 6 hours from that time in order to get my local time for the change, or not.

Comment: Could be wrong, but that may be more of a filesystem question than an excel one. See http://superuser.com/questions/109922/are-windows-file-timestamps-timezone-aware?rq=1