# Windows: are file attributes such as Date Modified and Date Created timezone aware?

Tags: windows

Basically, I'm looking for a yes/no answer to this question: [Are Windows file timestamps timezone aware?](https://superuser.com/questions/109922/are-windows-file-timestamps-timezone-aware)

example: a colleague creates a file in USA at 11AM (GMT-5), I copy this file onto my laptop, which has the UK time-zone settings (GMT in winter). What's the time am i going to see as a value of "Modified Date" file attribute?

Comment: As there are differences due to used file system and type of transport there is no clear yes/no answer as the accepted answer to your linked question clearly points out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes" for NTFS and "no" for FAT/FAT32 disk formats.

Microsoft article
[File Times](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/file-times)
says:

> The NTFS file system stores time values in UTC format, so they are not affected by changes in time zone or daylight saving time. The FAT file system stores time values based on the local time of the computer.